# How I get subscribed private channels in telegram for my user

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I try to create simple client for telegram in telethon. When I log my user in, I would like to get all channels where I am subscribed in. Do you have any idea how to do it? How I get the messages from then?

````py
self._client = TelegramClient('session_name1',
                                self._api_id,
                                self._api_hash)

self._client.connect()
        if not self._client.is_user_authorized():
            self._client.send_code_request(self._phone_number)
            self._me = self._client.sign_in(self._phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

result = self._client(functions.users.GetFullUserRequest(
            id=self._username))
print(result.stringify())
```python
````

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Wiki](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html)

You can user functions `self._client.get_dialogs()` and `self._client.get_messages()`